# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0 error while gradle sync

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I make new android things app with api level 24.
I got error msg during gradle build:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0.

My app build.gradle looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'
}
```

Thank you in any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by corporate proxy. Although i have setup proxy in android studio. It looks like gradle was not affected by it.
I just switched to android hotspot before start of gradle build and everything worked fine.